# Ejecutar funciones de una clase propia desde otra clase propia - Python

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo problemas al ejecutar elementos de una clase en otra clase.

Contexto: Estoy trabajando en archivos de extensión python independientes. Tengo uno que se llama `boot.py`, para el inicio del sistema, luego el `main.py` el cual ya se ejecuta el resto del tiempo y dos archivos más para dos clases que he creado, `myClock.py` y `LoRa_config.py`.

La cosa está en que en un inicio, en el `boot.py`, yo inicializo mi objeto reloj que vendrá de la ya mencionada clase propia, `myClock.py`.

```
# boot.py
import myClock
myclock = myClock.Clock()
```

Esta es mi clase `Clock`,

```
# myClock.py
class Clock:

    def __init__(self):
        self.seconds = 0
        self.time_LoRa = 30
        self.__alarm = Timer.Alarm(self.LoRa_clock_handler, self.time_LoRa, periodic=True)

    
    def LoRa_clock_handler(self, alarm):
        print('Tiempo LoRa:',self.time_LoRa)

    # Función para modificar remotamente el tiempo de envío de datos por LoRa.
    def time_LoRa_modify(self, new_time):
        self.time_LoRa = new_time
        self.__alarm = Timer.Alarm(self.LoRa_clock_handler, self.time_LoRa, periodic=True)
```

Y en un momento dado quiero modificar el valor de `time_LoRa`  que veis en la inicialización de la clase anterior. Por lo tanto debo ejecutar su función `time_LoRa_modify()`.

El **problema** viene aquí, pues la ejecución de esta función debo hacerla desde la otra clase creada por mi. Mi clase,

```
# LoRa_config.py
class myLoRa:

    # OTRAS FUNCIONES QUE NO INTERVIENEN EN ESTE PROBLEMA
    
    # Actuar según el downlink recibido
    def LoRa_downlink_handler(self, value):
        # Selector
        if value == 1:
            # ...
        elif value == 6:
            print('Modifico tiempo LoRa')
            myclock.time_LoRa_modify(10)
```

Hasta la función `LoRa_downlink_handler()` llego sin problemas, e incluso se me ejecuta el condicional sin problemas. Por lo tanto el problema viene cuando llamo a la función, `myclock.time_LoRa_modify(10)` (le meto un 10 como nuevo parámetro de tiempo).

El error es:

> NameError: name 'myclock' is not defined

Probé importando el objeto del `boot.py`, pero esto funciona mal, pues efectivamente me cambia el valor pero el valor y cada 10 segundos se ejecuta, pero el tiempo con el que se había inicializado sigue estando, `self.time_LoRa = 30`. Por lo tanto ahora trabaja con el nuevo tiempo (el que yo quiero) y el viejo (el que ya no debería estar).

```
elif value == 6:
    print('Modifico tiempo LoRa')
    from boot import myclock
    myclock.time_LoRa_modify(10)
```

Entiendo que en este caso estoy creando un nuevo objeto en vez de modificar el actual.

¿Alguien sabe que error cometo?

¡Gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método que uso para desarrollo en ambientes microPython es crear un script `config.py` donde poner todas las variables globales a la aplicación:

**config.py**

```
myclock = None
```

Luego voy inicializando esas variables donde sea adecuado:

**boot.py**

```
import config
config.myclock = myClock.Clock()
```

y cuando necesito usarlas, las importo

**LoRa_config.py**

```
import config

class myLoRa:

    # OTRAS FUNCIONES QUE NO INTERVIENEN EN ESTE PROBLEMA
    
    # Actuar según el downlink recibido
    def LoRa_downlink_handler(self, value):
        # Selector
        if value == 1:
            # ...
        elif value == 6:
            print('Modifico tiempo LoRa')
            config.myclock.time_LoRa_modify(10)
```

Este sistema es ordenado y me permite poner en un solo lugar todas las variables que se deben compartir entre módulos.

Comment: Super interesante esta manera, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia,

Al parecer no estas apuntando correctamente a la instancia de la clase `Clock`. Solo con esa instancia podrías acceder a los métodos de la clase `Clock` y la variable myclock se tiene que volver a instanciar después de cada importación.

Existen dos posibles soluciones para tu problema:

1. Tener una variable con la instancia de la clase `Clock` en el archivo que la vas a utilizar y llamarla para utilizar su método.
2. Convertir la clase Clock en un `singleton`. Para aclarar un `singleton` es una figura en programación que le impide crear a una clase instancias nuevas y siempre que se inicialize una esta llama por defecto a la primera instancia que se creo, con esta implementan no importa si tienes una variable o no la clase `Clock` siempre sera la misma úsese donde se use y no cambiara por cada ejecución del programa.

Los `singletons` son figuras tan antiguas como la programación misma pero aun se utilizan casi en todos los lenguajes de programación. El principal problema de los `singletons` es que suelen estar cargados siempre en memoria y una aplicación con muchos `singletons` es insostenible, por cada aplicación se recomienda un máximo de clases con esta característica pero creo que para tu problema particular te funcionara perfecto.

Adicional a esto te contare que existe otra figura mas que suele ir de la mano de los `singletons` y son los métodos estáticos.

Los métodos estáticos son métodos que no requieren que la clase se instancie por lo tanto no necesitan un `self` y se utilizan como métodos utilitarios de una clase que dependen de las funciones o atributos de esta.

Para marcar un método como estático utilizamos la anotación `@staticmethod`

Aquí va la solución a tu problema con un singleton:

Así quedaría tu clase `Clock`

```
class Clock:
    __instance = None

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():
        """ Static access method. """
        if Clock.__instance is None:
            Clock()
        return Clock.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        """ Virtually private constructor. """
        if Clock.__instance is not None:
            raise Exception("This class is a singleton!")
        else:
            Clock.__instance = self
        self.seconds = 0
        self.time_LoRa = 30
        self.__alarm = Timer.Alarm(self.LoRa_clock_handler, self.time_LoRa, periodic=True)


    def LoRa_clock_handler(self, alarm):
        print('Tiempo LoRa:', self.time_LoRa)

    # Función para modificar remotamente el tiempo de envío de datos por LoRa.
    @staticmethod
    def time_LoRa_modify(self, new_time):
        self.time_LoRa = new_time
        self.__alarm = Timer.Alarm(self.LoRa_clock_handler, self.time_LoRa, periodic=True)
```

Y asi seria su implentacion en otra clase:

```
    elif value == 6:
    print('Modifico tiempo LoRa')
    Clock.getInstance().time_LoRa_modify(10)
```

Cuéntame si te sirvió.

Un saludo :)