# Tengo que crear una class pero estoy teniendo problema

Tags: python, clase, class

tengo que hacer este ejercicio, pero estoy teniendo problemas, no se si estoy encaminada.

Crear una clase **Persona.**

Debe tener los atributos:

nombre, fecha, dni . cuentas( este debe ser una lista)

Crear método ****saludo****

retornar un saludo. Ejemplo: “hola { } “

Crear método ****crear_cuenta****

este método va a crear un objeto de la clase Cuenta

el objeto creado va a crear un nuevo movimiento usando la clase MovimientoCuenta

hasta ahora voy asi:

```
class Persona():
  
  def __init__(self, nombre, fecha_nacimiento, dni, lista_cuentas = [241511, 241520]):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento
    self.dni = dni
    self.lista_cuentas = lista_cuentas

  def saludo(nombre):
    print(f"¡Hola" + nombre + '!')

  def Nacimiento(fecha_nacimiento):
   print("Nací " + fecha_nacimiento)

   def documento(dni):
     print("Mi dni es" + dni)

   def cuentas(lista_cuentas):
      print("Mi número de cuenta es" + lista_cuentas)
```

Comment: ¿y cual es el problema que tienes? Entre más puntual sea con el problema, es más fácil ayudarte

Comment: el problema es que me bloquee ahí, soy novata en el tema programación, estoy aprendiendo

Comment: Creo que esto podría servirte https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258690/c%C3%B3mo-llamar-a-un-m%C3%A9todo-de-una-clase-desde-otra-clase-en-python https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/409114/ejecutar-funciones-de-una-clase-propia-desde-otra-clase-propia-python en ambas preguntas en las respuestas muestran métodos para acceder a funciones de otras clases. También sería útil saber algo sobre las clases que mencionas `Cuenta` `MovimientoCuenta`

Comment: No veo una pregunta aqui.

Comment: a mi me decís? y la pregunta sería: estoy bien encaminada? que me falta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias crear la clase Cuentas y ponerla en la lista que aparece y dice lista de cuentas,haci ya puedes modificar sus atributos y usar sus funciones.

```py
class Cuentas:
    def __init__(self,propietario):
        self.lista_de_cuentas=[]
        self.propietario=propietario
    def addCuenta(self,id_de_cuenta)
        self.lista_de_cuentas.append(id_de_cuenta)
```

`self.propietario` Debe se una clase persona y asi puedes saber cual es su nombre,dni,su fecha de nacimiento,etc...

bueno... me imagino que con esto ya te hagas una idea de a lo que me refiero.

si te fue uitl mi respuesya por favor apoyala positivamente :)

Comment: Hola, justamente me pide todo bien detallado como dice ahí, igual tu ejemplo me sirve para otro ejercicio que tambien tengo que hacer, justamente basado en cuentas

Comment: bueno amigo eso fue lo que entendi de todas formas si te sirve vota la respuesta a favor.

Comment: si, me re sirvió, muchas gracias